# ClearCase statistics for LOC, per user

Tags: clearcase

I'm looking for a ClearCase addin / command line tool that I can script that would allow me to get the total number of lines of code added/modified by a specific user for a specific time interval / VOB.

In my head, this should be possible, at least up to one point (the point where branches are deleted). What I don't know is if there's a tool to run diffs and extract data, or commands that extract branch info and then other commands that diff them that I could use.

Many thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

On the top of my head, one solution would be:

- make two dynamic views
- set a **[time-based selection rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577980/how-to-find-out-all-the-activities-happend-in-a-branch-in-the-last-month/1578508#1578508)**
- apply a diff between the two.

That being said, I don't know if there is a tool able to parse the result of a ClearCase diff for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use and parse the output from cleartool annotate, otherwise you'll need to walk through the version tree for every element, note the creator for each version, and perform a diff for every sub-sequence of versions created by the same user.

Answer (score -3):

Check [this white paper](http://bit.ly/15AFT2d). It deals with LOC metrics for ClearCase and provides some examples.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, as link-rot happens. Please include at least a summary of what can be found in a link.